# How do you centre a background image div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking at http://www.hideoutfestival.com/

When you resize your screen, the header background image is continually centered.

I can't seem to replicate this effect.

I have:

```
<div id="cover" style="background:url(/design/cover.jpg) repeat-x top">
</div>
```

And

```
#cover {
    height:450px;
    width:100%;
background-position: center;
}
```

Yet I can't seem to have the same effect as they do.

Any help?

Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the background-position in your inline styles is possibly overriding your CSS.
Try using `background-image: url(/design/cover.jpg);` inline and using this CSS:

```
#cover {
    height:450px;
    width:100%;
    background-repeat: x
    background-position: center top;
}
```

Or putting the whole thing into your style sheet is a better idea, but I'm assuming you have a reason for putting it inline. If you do decide to do that, this should work:

```
#cover {
    height:450px;
    width:100%;
    background-repeat: url(/design/cover.jpg) repeat-x center top;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. this still doesn't seem to be working. See the site here: http://bit.ly/10zWyvZ

Comment: Dud link - but if you mean http://festifinder.com/design/ then it seems to work for me - although you should add [`background-size: cover`](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) so that it covers the whole background.

Answer (score 3):

Inline CSS overrides external CSS. Any background properties set in the CSS are overridden by your inline rule.

Either change it so the background is positioned inline:

```
background:url(/design/cover.jpg) repeat-x center center;
```

Or change it so that just the image is defined on the element:

```
background-image:url(/design/cover.jpg);
```

Or move it to your stylesheet (which you *really* should do).

Comment: Hmm. this still doesn't seem to be working. See the site here: http://bit.ly/10zWyvZ